# Assigning an array match to a string

Tags: c++

My program has two stored arrays and an unassigned string:

```
std::string array1 = "red blue green white";
std::string array2 = "white purple yellow red";
std::string str = "";
```

I can use `array1.find(array2)` to find if there is a match, but how do I get that match and assign the match to `std::string str`.

Looking for a solution as shown below :

```
if (array1.find(array2)) str = match;
```

Comment: What is a match?

Comment: `find` returns the position of the match, you should be able to use that. But I don't think you understand what `find` does -- it won't detect any matches between those strings.

Comment: Please provide an example with your desired output. Anyways, this sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Split your strings into vector of strings with space as delimiter and use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection to find strings that are present in both vectors. Construct your str from the resulting vector

Comment: What would you do if `array1` and `array2` have multiple strings matching ?

Comment: You should probably check what does `string::substr()` do

Comment: Naming a std::string as "array" does not make it one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string::substr` and a for loop to find which of your entries will match.

Example:

```
std::string theString = "red blue green white";
std::vector<std::string> vectStr = {"white", "purple", "yellow", "red"};
std::string match = "";

for(auto &str : vectStr)
{
    auto pos = theString.find(str);
    if(pos != std::string::npos)
    {
         match = theString.substr(pos, str.length());
    }
}
```

Then you can do a basic check if the string is still empty after the loop which will mean - no match.
This will get you the last match in the string. You can do an early return in the if statement to get the first match if that behavior is desired.

If you cannot create the vector initially (the parameter come as a whole string) you can split the string and create the vector(if there is a separator - for example, whitespace).
Since I'm not aware of a standard `string::split` you can use `boost` or implement it yourself. There are plenty of examples out there.

Comment: I think he does not have a vector of strings available, he just has a string( hopefully separated with spaces ). In such a case, maybe you can add splitting the strings w.r.t spaces, adding it to the vector in your answer ? Would look more complete imho.